# Make change to one row and reflect the results in other cells

Tags: reactjs

In my `Row Details` where I have a table of multiple rows. And some of the row data are getting fetched from the `data` props. I'm trying to change the `Transfer` column where the `Total` will change automatically with `Rate*Transfer` calculation. But when I change the data of one row, the other rows get affected too. I also have a row of `Grand Total` where I would like to display all the totals of all `Total`. Initially I've used `useEffect` to load the `Total` columns. But it shows `NaN` value. So how do I change on cell only and show the result to that specific row without affecting other rows.

```
export default function RowDetails({ open, handleClose, data }) {
  const [total, setTotal] = React.useState(1);

  // console.log(Rate, Stock, Transfer);
  const [transfer, setTransfer] = useState(0);

  const { Rate, Stock, Transfer } = data;

  const columns = [
    {
      field: "Lot",
      headerName: "Lot#",
      width: 200,
      editable: false,
    },
    { field: "Bill", headerName: "Bill#", width: 130, editable: false },
    {
      field: "Shelf",
      headerName: "Shelf",
      width: 200,
      editable: false,
    },
    {
      field: "Bin",
      headerName: "Bin",
      width: 200,
      editable: false,
    },
    {
      field: "Rate",
      headerName: "Rate",
      width: 200,
      editable: false,
    },
    {
      field: "Stock",
      headerName: "Stock Balance Qty.",
      width: 200,
      editable: false,
    },
    {
      field: "Transfer",
      headerName: "Transfer Qty.",
      width: 200,
      editable: true,
    },
    {
      field: "Total",
      headerName: "Total",
      width: 200,
      editable: false,
    },
  ];

  const [defaultRows, setDefaultRows] = useState([
    {
      id: 1,
      Lot: "2101000134",
      Bill: "M0000013092",
      Shelf: "W13-A1",
      Bin: "B01",
      Rate: Rate,
      Stock: Stock,
      Transfer: Transfer,
      Total: Rate * Transfer,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      Lot: "2101000134",
      Bill: "M0000013092",
      Shelf: "W13-A1",
      Bin: "B01",
      Rate: Rate,
      Stock: Stock,
      Transfer: Transfer,
      Total: Rate * Transfer,
    },
  ]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTotal(Rate * transfer);
  }, [transfer]);

  const handleChange = (e, id) => {
    console.log(id);
    setTransfer(e.target.value);
    //setDefaultRows(...defaultRows, (defaultRows[id].Transfer = e.target.value));
    console.log("id", defaultRows[id].Transfer);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Dialog
        fullScreen
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        TransitionComponent={Transition}
      >
        
        <div style={{ height: 400, width: "100%" }}>
          <table className="dataTable">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                {columns.map((column) => (
                  <th key={column.headerName}>{column.headerName}</th>
                ))}
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {defaultRows.map((row) => (
                <tr key={row.id}>
                  <td>{row.Lot}</td>
                  <td>{row.Bill}</td>
                  <td>{row.Shelf}</td>
                  <td>{row.Bin}</td>
                  <td>{Rate}</td>
                  <td>{Stock}</td>
                  <td>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, row.id)} //getting the row id and value
                      value={transfer}
                    />
                  </td>
                  <td>{total}</td>
                </tr>
              ))}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <table className="totalTable">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Grand Total</th>
              <th>{total}</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
        </table>
      </Dialog>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Edit 2]**: Since you seems to be completely lost in your data (It happens), here is the complete guideline to make your component works.
First you should fix your error :
In App:

- `const [rowData, setRowData] = React.useState();` remove the empty object so `rowData` is undefined
- Delay the display of your modal by moving the `setOpen` in a new `useEffect` as follow : `React.useEffect(() => setOpen(true), [rowData]);`
- Wrap your `RowDetails` as follow : `{rowData && (<RowDetails .../>)}`

In RowDetails :

- Uncomment the lines in `defaultRows`.`DefaultRows` is the object you want to edit.
  Your two states `rowData` and `transfer` are useless here since they are already in the prop `data`. If you need to update it, you'll have to pass a function from the parent to do it. so:
- Remove the two states `rowData` and `transfer`
- Set your `defaultRows` with an empty state: `const [defaultRows, setDefaultRows] = useState();`.
- Create a useEffect that is triggered each time the `data` prop changes. This way, the value will correspond to the clicked row in the `App` component. This useEffect obviously set the `defaultRows` : `useEffect(() => { setDefaultRows([...]; }, [data]);`
- Edit the errored line: it should be `data` instead of `rowData` and your `setTransfer` in the onChange of the input become the function used to edit your object `defaultRows` (`setDataFromParent` in my Stackblitz, it just doesn't come from the parent here since you don't want your row in a sub component). The input `defaultValue` (Not `value`, I changed it since I recall a bug about it but I might be wrong so do as you pleased) is `row.transfer` now I guess (since each row has its own transfer property). Here the method and the associated modifications:

```
const [defaultRows, setDefaultRows] = useState();

  // When data changes, you have to update your defaultRows object
  useEffect(() => {
    setDefaultRows([
      {
        id: 1,
        Lot: "2101000134",
        Bill: "M0000013092",
        Shelf: "W13-A1",
        Bin: "B01",
        Rate: data.Rate,
        Stock: data.Stock,
        Transfer: data.Transfer,
        Total: data.Rate * data.Transfer,
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        Lot: "2101000134",
        Bill: "M0000013092",
        Shelf: "W13-A1",
        Bin: "B01",
        Rate: data.Rate,
        Stock: data.Stock,
        Transfer: data.Transfer,
        Total: data.Rate * data.Transfer,
      }
    ]);
  }, [data]);
  
  const calculateTotal = React.useCallback(() => {
    if(defaultRows){
      let total = 0;
      defaultRows.forEach((row) => {
        total += row.Rate * row.Transfer;
      });
      setTotal(total);
    }
  }, [defaultRows]);

  useEffect(() => {
    calculateTotal();
  }, [defaultRows, calculateTotal]);

  const setNewDefaultRows = (newTransferValue, rowIndex) => {
    const newDefaultRows = [...defaultRows];
    const currentRow = newDefaultRows[rowIndex];
    // Edit the transfer value of the row and its total
    currentRow.Transfer = Number(newTransferValue);
    currentRow.Total = currentRow.Rate * currentRow.Transfer;

    setDefaultRows(newDefaultRows);
  }
```

Notice the `usecallback`. CodeSandbox told me to add it and to add `calculateTotal` as dependency of the `useEffect`. I don't master the use of useCallback but it is used to retrigger the useEffect here (Remember, I said in my example I didn't know why the useEffect wasn't triggered after the update of the state. useCallback is the answer).

- Either add a return statement that return an empty fragment or just a condition before the map : `{ defaultRows && defaultRows.map(...)}` (In `<tbody>` tag). You don't want to display `defaultRows` before it's ready is ready :
- Change the `total` of your row for `row.Total`

You should now have everything working : No bug when accessing the `RowDetails.js`, the total per row, the total at the bottom.

Now, I made it depending on what I have understood of your code and your needs. It might be a bit different, maybe you need this state `transfer`, it's your call to adapt.

Here is the complete code of your component :

```
export default function RowDetails({ open, handleClose, data }) {
  const [total, setTotal] = React.useState(1);

  const columns = [
    {
      field: "Lot",
      headerName: "Lot#",
      width: 200,
      editable: false
    },
    { field: "Bill", headerName: "Bill#", width: 130, editable: false },
    {
      field: "Shelf",
      headerName: "Shelf",
      width: 200,
      editable: false
    },
    {
      field: "Bin",
      headerName: "Bin",
      width: 200,
      editable: false
    },
    {
      field: "Rate",
      headerName: "Rate",
      width: 200,
      editable: false
    },
    {
      field: "Stock",
      headerName: "Stock Balance Qty.",
      width: 200,
      editable: false
    },
    {
      field: "Transfer",
      headerName: "Transfer Qty.",
      width: 200,
      editable: true
    },
    {
      field: "Total",
      headerName: "Total",
      width: 200,
      editable: false
    }
  ];

  const [defaultRows, setDefaultRows] = useState();

  // When data changes, you have to update your defaultRows object
  useEffect(() => {
    setDefaultRows([
      {
        id: 1,
        Lot: "2101000134",
        Bill: "M0000013092",
        Shelf: "W13-A1",
        Bin: "B01",
        Rate: data.Rate,
        Stock: data.Stock,
        Transfer: data.Transfer,
        Total: data.Rate * data.Transfer,
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        Lot: "2101000134",
        Bill: "M0000013092",
        Shelf: "W13-A1",
        Bin: "B01",
        Rate: data.Rate,
        Stock: data.Stock,
        Transfer: data.Transfer,
        Total: data.Rate * data.Transfer,
      }
    ]);
  }, [data]);
  
  const calculateTotal = React.useCallback(() => {
    if(defaultRows){
      let total = 0;
      defaultRows.forEach((row) => {
        total += row.Rate * row.Transfer;
      });
      setTotal(total);
    }
  }, [defaultRows]);

  useEffect(() => {
    calculateTotal();
  }, [defaultRows, calculateTotal]);

  const setNewDefaultRows = (newTransferValue, rowIndex) => {
    const newDefaultRows = [...defaultRows];
    const currentRow = newDefaultRows[rowIndex];
    // Edit the transfer value of the row and its total
    currentRow.Transfer = Number(newTransferValue);
    currentRow.Total = currentRow.Rate * currentRow.Transfer;

    setDefaultRows(newDefaultRows);
  }
  if(!defaultRows) return <></>;
  return (
    <div>
      <Dialog
        fullScreen
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        TransitionComponent={Transition}
      >
        <AppBar sx={{ position: "relative" }}>
          <Toolbar>
            <Breadcrumbs aria-label="breadcrumb">
              <Link underline="hover" color="inherit" href="/">
                MUI
              </Link>
              <Link
                underline="hover"
                color="inherit"
                href="/getting-started/installation/"
              >
                Core
              </Link>
              <Typography color="text.primary">Breadcrumbs</Typography>
            </Breadcrumbs>
            <Box sx={{ flex: "1" }}></Box>
            <IconButton
              edge="start"
              color="inherit"
              onClick={handleClose}
              aria-label="close"
            >
              <CloseIcon />
            </IconButton>
          </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
        <div style={{ height: 400, width: "100%" }}>
          <table className="dataTable">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                {columns.map((column) => (
                  <th key={column.headerName}>{column.headerName}</th>
                ))}
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {defaultRows.map((row, i) => (
                <tr key={row.id}>
                  <td>{row.Lot}</td>
                  <td>{row.Bill}</td>
                  <td>{row.Shelf}</td>
                  <td>{row.Bin}</td>
                  <td>{data.Rate}</td>
                  <td>{data.Stock}</td>
                  <td>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      onChange={(e) => setNewDefaultRows (e.target.value, i)}
                      value={row.Transfer}
                    />
                  </td>
                  <td>{row.Total}</td>
                </tr>
              ))}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <table className="totalTable">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Total</th>
              <th>{total}</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
        </table>
      </Dialog>
    </div>
  );
}
```

---

**[Edit]**: As explained in the comments, creating a state for each row may be a better idea. Here is [a n example on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-functional-boilerplate-16-13-1-gncnbt?file=index.js) of how you can achieve what you want. I didn't recreate everything from your projet but the functionalities are the same I guess. Here is the code :

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import './style.css';

const App = () => {
  const headers = ['Name', 'Money in pocket', 'Money in bank', 'Total per row'];

  const dataFromApi = [
    { name: 'Quentin', moneyPocket: 48, moneyBank: 1232 },
    { name: 'John', moneyPocket: 10, moneyBank: 543 },
    { name: 'Julian', moneyPocket: 4005, moneyBank: 0 },
  ];
  // Similar to your defaultRows
  const [data, setData] = React.useState(dataFromApi);
  const [total, setTotal] = React.useState(0);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    calculateTotal();
  }, []);

  const calculateTotal = () => {
    // Calcultate the total money of all rows
    let totalMoney = 0;

    data.map((d) => {
      totalMoney += d.moneyPocket + d.moneyBank;
    });

    setTotal(totalMoney);
  };

  // Update the row in the state and recalculate the total
  // For some reason I couldn't do it through the useEffect (by adding data in the dependency array)
  const setDataFromParent = (rowData, i) => {
    let newData = data;
    newData[i] = rowData;

    setData(newData);
    calculateTotal();
  };

  return (
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          {headers.map((header) => (
            <th key={Math.random()}>{header}</th>
          ))}
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {data.map((d, i) => (
          <CustomRow
            key={Math.random()}
            data={d}
            index={i}
            setRow={setDataFromParent}
          />
        ))}
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td>{total}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
};

const CustomRow = ({ data, index, setRow }) => {
  const [rowData, setRowData] = React.useState(data);

  // When rowData changes, edit the parent component with its given function.
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (JSON.stringify(rowData) !== JSON.stringify(data)) {
      setRow(rowData, index);
    }
  }, [rowData]);

  // When you change the value, update the local useState
  // Which reflect the changes in the total per row (rerender)
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setRowData({
      ...data,
      moneyPocket: Number(e.target.value),
      total: Number(e.target.value) + data.moneyBank,
    });
  };

  return (
    <tr>
      <td>{data.name}</td>
      <td>
        <input
          type="number"
          defaultValue={data.moneyPocket}
          onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
        />
      </td>
      <td>{data.moneyBank}</td>
      <td>{rowData.moneyPocket + rowData.moneyBank}</td>
    </tr>
  );
};

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

And a bit of css :

```
td {
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

input {
  width: 100px;
  border: none;
}
```

The second column is an input so you can edit the value and notice that the total per row changes as well as the total of all row.

---

If you want to change `tranfer` and have only one row impacted, you should create a component for each `transfer input` (or each row, depending on if you example is full or not). This way, you'll be able to move the state `const [transfer, setTransfer] = useState(0);` to the new component and so stop impacting every input field when changing one. Since you can pass a function as prop, you'll still be able to update your parent data with whatever function you want.

So you'll have something like :

```
const TransferField = ({ funcFromParentOne, setTotal, id }) => {
  const [transfer, setTransfer] = useState(0);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    // Do what you want to impact your parent, based on the id
    // ...
    //  setTotal(...);
  }, [transfert]);
  
  return (
    <input
      type="text"
      onChange={(e) => setTransfer(e.target.value)}
      value={transfer}
    />
  );
};
```

And in your parent:

```
{defaultRows.map((row, i) => (
  <tr key={row.id}>
    <td>{row.Lot}</td>
    <td>{row.Bill}</td>
    <td>{row.Shelf}</td>
    <td>{row.Bin}</td>
    <td>{Rate}</td>
    <td>{Stock}</td>
    <td>
      <TransfertField id={i} /> {/* and other props */}
    </td>
    <td>{total}</td>
  </tr>
))}
```

Comment: But will i get the individual total values from each row to set the `grand total` cell?

Comment: @buzz You could simply write the calcul for the total in the cell if you don't need it anywhere else. else then just create a component for the row instead of just the input, and you'll pass the data as prop. This way, you'll be able to calcultate everything you want that is related to a specific row inside this component. I guess this is even better for futur evolution of your app

Comment: I tried your way but I'm a bit confused here. I got the separate component for input's concept. But what getting me confused is the `useEffect` in `TransferField` and how do i use the `functionFromParentOne`. Could you please be more specific.

Comment: I mean inside the useEffect() if I were to access the `Rate` Then I've to also pass `data` as props in the `TransferField` right? otherwise how I am going to change the total value?

Comment: @buzz I edited my answer to give you an example of how you can achieve it with a `CustomRow` component. What I created isn't a repro of your code but i still easy to adapt to your case I think. Don't hesitate is there is something obscure for you of If I made a mistake.

Comment: I followed your code...But there's one problem, in my code the table opens up in an additional dialog box where I make the changes. so in that dialog box I passed the `data` as prop. which is not loading at first, as a result I'm getting `undefined`. https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-banzai-6jvlm?file=/src/App.js you can check my whole code here also check the console. you can also see initially I'm getting `NaN` in the total field.

Comment: @buzz RowDetails contains the table where you can edit the data, so this is the table that needs to have a component for each row. You didn't reproduce that so calculation are made the same for all the rows (Your `transfer` state is used by all the rows, but maybe it's on purpose, I don't know). Also, you are not using `setRowData`. I think it's better to create a component for your rows, but if you don't want to, you need to manipulate your rowData to set the correct value for the proper row (something like `rowData[i]`).

Comment: Concerning the `NaN` and the error you get in the console, that's because your modal in loaded with default value, even if you don't click on an icon to open it. It is loaded, but hidden. That means it tries to calculate the total with undefined values. The error might break the code and so nothing works after that. You need to avoid this error by either loading your component only when your `rowData` (in App.js) is ready with all the data, or by doing the calculation (in rowDetails.js) when your props data has all the needed values

Comment: about your first solution `rowData[i]` , I did something like this way before posting the problem...you can even see it in my `handleChange()` in the question..didn't work...for the second solution, I tried delaying the load time by using `setTimeOut()` so that the data loads first then the `useEffect()` runs...didn't work either

Comment: @buzz I edited my answer. I should have to do that but you seem to be lost with your data and what you need to do. In this case, I highly recommand you so stop, and build a minimized version of the workflow you want (as the stackblitz I gave you before).

Comment: thank you for your time and patience...you made this easier...the grand total is changing but all the rows are still affected by this...hopefully i'll figure this one out by following your guideline.

Comment: but one more thing, idk if you've noticed...after making changes in `RowDetails` when you exit the dialog and go back to `App` and click another row, the `total` values from previous row still exists

Comment: You're welcome, glad I can help. I edited my answer to add what's needed. About the total, I bet you didn't replace `total` by `row.Total` or something liek that. For the exit dialog, I added it in my answer : you need to update your `defaultRows` when `data` changes